# How can I extract the value of only one value along with the key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.8

For example,

```
books={1001:['Inferno','Dan Brown','Anchor Books','Thriller',42.00,70],
       1002:['As You Like It','William Shakespear','Penguin Publications','Classics',20.00,54],
       1003:['The Kite Runner','Khaled Hosseini','Bloomsbury Publcations','Fiction',30.00,70],
       1004:['A Thousand Splendid Suns','Khaled Hosseini','Bloomsbury Publications','Fiction',35.00,70],
       1005:['The Girl on The Train','Paula Hawkins','Riverhead Books','Fiction',28.00,100],
       1006:['The Alchemist','Paulo Coelho','Rupa Books','Fiction',25.00,50]}
```

How can I display only the key and the book's name?

Comment: Which key and which book? Or do you want to iterate over all the keys?

Comment: if you want all keys value as a list of tuples use `[(key, val[0]) for key,val in books.items()]`, if you want a dictionary of `key:bookname` use `{key: val[0] for key,val in books.items()}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want all the key and the book names:

```
books={1001:['Inferno','Dan Brown','Anchor Books','Thriller',42.00,70],
       1002:['As You Like It','William Shakespear','Penguin Publications','Classics',20.00,54],
       1003:['The Kite Runner','Khaled Hosseini','Bloomsbury Publcations','Fiction',30.00,70],
       1004:['A Thousand Splendid Suns','Khaled Hosseini','Bloomsbury Publications','Fiction',35.00,70],
       1005:['The Girl on The Train','Paula Hawkins','Riverhead Books','Fiction',28.00,100],
       1006:['The Alchemist','Paulo Coelho','Rupa Books','Fiction',25.00,50]}

for key, (book_name, *book_info) in books.items():
    print(key, book_name)
```

Output:

```
1001 Inferno
1002 As You Like It
1003 The Kite Runner
1004 A Thousand Splendid Suns
1005 The Girl on The Train
1006 The Alchemist
```

**EXPLANATION**:

Here `*` operator is used for tuple packing or unpacking. For e.g.:

```
>>> book = ['Inferno','Dan Brown','Anchor Books','Thriller',42.00,70]
>>> book_name, *book_info = book
>>> print(book_name)
Inferno
>>> print(book_info)
['Dan Brown', 'Anchor Books', 'Thriller', 42.0, 70]
```

So here the first element of the list is assigned to `book_name`, then the rest of the elements are packed into the `book_info` using the `*` operator.
So when you are iterating over `books.items`, for each iteration you get the key, value pair. For the first iteration, the key,value pair would look like this:

```
>>> pair = (1001, ['Inferno', 'Dan Brown', 'Anchor Books', 'Thriller', 42.0, 70])
# so,
>>> key, (book_name, *book_info) = (1001, ['Inferno', 'Dan Brown', 'Anchor Books', 'Thriller', 42.0, 70])
>>> print(key)
1001
>>> print(book_name)
Inferno
>>> print(book_info)
['Dan Brown', 'Anchor Books', 'Thriller', 42.0, 70]
```

First value in the tuple is assigned to `key`, and the second value in the tuple, which is a list, gets assigned to `(book_name, *book_info)`.

Reference:
[PEP 3132 -- Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Otherwise, if you have a key:

```
#say:
key = 1001
print(f'{key} : {books[key][0]}')
```

Output:

```
1001 : Inferno
```

**Unpacking Example**

```
>>> book_ids, book_names = zip(*[(key, book_name) for key, (book_name, *_) in books.items()])
>>> book_ids
(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006)
>>> book_names
('Inferno',
 'As You Like It',
 'The Kite Runner',
 'A Thousand Splendid Suns',
 'The Girl on The Train',
 'The Alchemist')
```

Comment: Upvote partially because it's right but mostly because I *love* f-strings :-)

Comment: What does *books_info mean? Where did we get that variable from?

Pretty new to python, sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: It is called packing/unpacking in Python. I will explain, let me edit.

Comment: @ArunimaS.K. please check the edit, I have added a reference to the Python docs on packing and unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

If you know index of book name and it will always be at the same place. you could do something like this:

```
for key, book_data in books.items():
    print key, book_data[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just access the relevant book key and get the 0th element of the value list.

```
key = input("What is your book key?")
print (key, books[key][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner answer:

```
[print(key,books[key][0]) for key in books.keys()]
```